# Unsafe class in Android?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Do the Android Dalvik standard libraries have any class similar to the undocumented class sun.misc.Unsafe in Java SE which allows direct access to memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android implements parts of sun.misc.Unsafe, primarily to support the JSR-166 concurrency classes.  It's not part of the Android API.

Comment: You can call unsafe APIs via reflection, and use the 'catch' clause to fall back in case unsafe is not available.

Answer (score 3):

It has the JNI bridge which could allow for just about anything but it's not "unsafe" since you have to code that into your app. As far as I know there is no exposed way to get out of the JVM sandbox (at least not without finding an exploit).